htaccess with deny from IP how many admissible lines?
how many "deny from" lines are acceptable in a .htaccess
Hello everybody,
I have a system adding automaticaly in my .htaccees deny from IPxxxxxx lines when a visitor makes more than 10 connexions per minute to my website, I've done this system because any entry add a line to my database and I want to block any bad crawlers/user/hacker/
the problem is that after 1 year my .htaccess as more than 1000 entry lines, question :
any problem if my .htaccess as a lot of "deny from" lines and at your advice how many lines are acceptable ???
thanks for your response, Luis

The http server will still have to process all those incoming requests. Instead the usual approach is to already block such addresses in the package firewall, so on network level. That uses much less resources.
